# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I get this every time I use my Mysql PDO class:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? WHERE ?' at line 1
```

Heres the code:

```
function mysql_execute_safe_search($table, $where, $query){
    global $db;

    try{
        $preparedQuery = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM ? WHERE ?");

        $preparedQuery->execute([$table, $where, $query]);
        return $preparedQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } 

    catch(PDOException $Exception){

        echo $Exception->getMessage();

        return;
    }
}
```

Heres how I execute:

```
$search_query = mysql_execute_safe_search("people", "name", "Nathan");
```

Comment: placeholders can only be used for values. field/table names, or any other NON-value in an sql statement cannot be replaced. e.g. `->prepare("? ? ? ?")` -> `('SELECT', '*', 'FROM', 'foo')` is outright illegal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't bind a table name:

```
$preparedQuery = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE ?");
```

Comment: Aha, thought that might be the case. Thank you!

Comment: I learned this a few months ago. One remembers after that. **+1** for sure ;-)